# Implement delete repeat function with pointer

Tags: c++

I confuse how to implement shift left function to replace the repeating element.
I try to comment the best I can on my code.
Please point out my mistake, so i can fix it myself.

```
template <typename T>
void shift_left(T *a, int &a_size)
{
    T*b ;  // walker to check if the same element
    b=a;    //point b to a address
    b++;    //move b to the next element
    int *endptr;    //declare end pointer
    endptr += a_size;   // end pointer to the end
    int *c;     // c pointer to shift element back
    int i =0, j;    
    while (i < a_size && b != endptr)   //true when counter smaller than 
                                //arr size and b point not at the end
    {
        if (*a != *b)           
        {
            b++;        //increment b if a !=b
        }
        else if (*a == *b) // a ==b 
        {
            *b = *b++;  // replace next element with b element
            a_size--;   //reduct arr size
        }
    }
    for (j = 0; j < a_size; j++) // print out array loop
    {
        cout<< *a << "\t";
        a++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please make a [mcve] out of it (by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63737723/edit) the question) where you give the function some input and show us the output you get as well as the output you expect.

Comment: `*b = *b++;`does not do what you think it does.

Comment: Also, `endptr` isn't initialized. You should initialize it to point at `a`. It should also not be an `int*` but a `T*`.

Answer (score 2):

> Please point out my mistake, so i can fix it myself.

You ignored your compiler warnings.

Problem is, the code you posted alone will not trigger many warnings or errors (gcc only complains about `cout`). You have to help the compiler a bit by instantiating the template:

```
int main() {
    auto f = shift_left<int>;
}
```

With gcc I turn on more warnings via `-Wall` (it is not really "all" but rather "all common ones"), I want warnings as erors via `-Werror`, and get the following [output](https://godbolt.org/z/61YTf3):

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:32:10: error: unused variable 'f' [-Werror=unused-variable]
   32 |     auto f = shift_left<int>;
      |          ^
<source>: In instantiation of 'void shift_left(T*, int&) [with T = int]':
<source>:32:14:   required from here
<source>:20:13: error: operation on 'b' may be undefined [-Werror=sequence-point]
   20 |             *b = *b++;  // replace next element with b element
      |             ^
<source>:20:13: error: operation on 'b' may be undefined [-Werror=sequence-point]
<source>:9:10: error: unused variable 'c' [-Werror=unused-variable]
    9 |     int *c;     // c pointer to shift element back
      |          ^
<source>: In function 'void shift_left(T*, int&) [with T = int]':
<source>:8:12: error: 'endptr' is used uninitialized in this function [-Werror=uninitialized]
    8 |     endptr += a_size;   // end pointer to the end
      |     ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
```

The first is just unsused `f` in `main`, we can ignore that for now. Then `*b = *b++` is most probably wrong. `c` appears to be unused and `endptr` is used uninitialized.

The `main` above merely instantiates the template. As next step you want to actually call the function to test it. You want to use input for which you know what output to expect so you can compare. If they match you probably didn't test enough and if they don't you want to use a debugger to find the bugs in your code.